# DataFrame bar plot in subplots doesn't show xlabels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple subplots using the `DataFrame` `.plot()` function. It appears that the `xlabel` is appearing only in the last row.

[image: xlabel not appearing - example]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1)
for ax in axs:
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
    df.index.name = 'Xlabel'
    df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)    
plt.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

Is there any workaround for getting the `xlabel` in each row?

Comment: Your code looks fine, it shows the label for me when I run it (in ipython, pandas 0.17.1, matplotlib 1.5.0). This suggests something differs with your matplotlib configuration. Have you tried without tight_layout, for instance, or checked the `backend` you are using?

Comment: Thanks for checking it. I will update my packages and give it a go.

Comment: @StefanJansen Updating the packages solves the problem. If you post it as an answer, I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, it shows the label for me when I run it (in ipython, pandas 0.17.1, matplotlib 1.5.0). This suggests something differs with your matplotlib configuration.